# Script rest api from Ensembl generating error

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I am trying to run this script `restapi.py` from [ensembl](http://rest.ensembl.org/documentation/info/assembly_translation#python2one), but it generates this error below. Please help me fix it.

restapi.py

```
import requests, sys

server = "http://grch37.rest.ensembl.org"
ext = "/map/translation/ENSP00000288602/100..300?"

r = requests.get(server+ext, headers={ "Content-Type" : "application/json"})

if not r.ok:
  r.raise_for_status()
  sys.exit()

decoded = r.json()
print repr(decoded)
```

The error I am receiving:

```
File "restapi.py", line 13 print repr(decoded)
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: @DimitrisJim python --version
Python 3.4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remember that in Python 3.x [`print` is a function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print). 
As such, you'll need to add the required parenthesis around it to invoke the call:

```
print(repr(decode))
```

With this change, your script works just fine and returns a result of:

```
{'mappings': 
[{'assembly_name': 'GRCh37', 'start': 140534409, 'strand': -1, 'coord_system': 'chromosome', 'seq_region_name': '7', 'gap': 0, 'end': 140534615, 'rank': 0}, 
 {'assembly_name': 'GRCh37', 'start': 140508692, 'strand': -1, 'coord_system': 'chromosome', 'seq_region_name': '7', 'gap': 0, 'end': 140508795, 'rank': 0}, 
 {'assembly_name': 'GRCh37', 'start': 140507760, 'strand': -1, 'coord_system': 'chromosome', 'seq_region_name': '7', 'gap': 0, 'end': 140507862, 'rank': 0}, 
 {'assembly_name': 'GRCh37', 'start': 140501212, 'strand': -1, 'coord_system': 'chromosome', 'seq_region_name': '7', 'gap': 0, 'end': 140501360, 'rank': 0}, 
 {'assembly_name': 'GRCh37', 'start': 140500242, 'strand': -1, 'coord_system': 'chromosome', 'seq_region_name': '7', 'gap': 0, 'end': 140500281, 'rank': 0}]
}
```

Comment: Sure I will. Could you also let me know what could be the reason for this error I was getting while running it directly from the terminal using python in usr/bin/:  `File "restapi.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests, sys
ImportError: No module named requests`

Comment: I had pip `requests` installed in /usr/bin  and python was in usr/local/bin. Is that why?

Comment: Yup, you probably installed `requests` with another version of python (`python3.4`) while  `usr/bin` holds the python distribution that comes by default with your machine (probably `python 2.7.4`). You shouldn't really worry about that since you generally shouldn't use the python in `usr/bin`.

Comment: Thanks. I am actually using python in virtual environment. I am new to Python. Could you suggest me better IDE I can use for python?

Comment: I mainly use [`Sublime`](http://www.sublimetext.com/) and/or [`PyCharm`](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/specials/pycharm/pycharm.jsp?gclid=CjwKEAiAmqayBRDLgsfGiMmkxT0SJADHFUhP4Q8vY-IAMmpPfNQBZBvmiwgtihI0U0UPxi0ecUW_DRoCEIXw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) Both have free versions but the latter is probably better if you are just beggining. :-)

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!